# How can I loop thru a listview and getting the text from textviews in each row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, textview

I've got this custom listview and want to loop thru it, getting the text from a textview in each row. 
This is the essential of my code:

```
private TextView totalColumn;


totalColumn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.column3);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

for(int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++){
    String p = totalColumn.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

I can't see what im doing worng
The syso is giving me a Nullpointer.
The getCount() = 4, so thats not the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The stacktrace provides the exact line and column that is causing the error. Please post it and tell us which line is the one provided by the stack trace.

Comment: The nullpointer is accusing where I set String p = totalColumn.getText().toString();

Comment: Then `totalColumn` is null.

Comment: btw why are you looping trough the array if it always going to return the same value?

Comment: What has totalCollum to do with the listview? Moreover you use the whole for loop the same. And are not using i.

Comment: totalColumn is a textview in the row in the listview. The purpose of this is getting the total of each totalColumn put together. But I can't do that if I can't even get the text from the textview

Answer (score 1):

A null pointer is probably given when it reaches an array slot that it doesn't exists.
try

```
int i=0; i < shoppingL.size(); i++
```

Comment: there is nothing called shoppingL.size()

Answer (score 1):

To get all texts from the textviews in your listview is a wrong approch as there might be more items in the listview then there are visible. The right way is to retrieve the texts from the adapter.

Comment: Do you mean in my custom adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Listview holds that rows which are currently viewing. can not create all the row at  a time. You can save the created view from

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){}

callback method.

and save in  collection (Arraylist) and go through to the end of the list view and iterate the collection then you will get your result.